# Enriching objects inside AutoMapper's Profile is a good practice?

Tags: c#, automapper

Suppose you have the following object:

```
public class Invoice 
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

And this one:

```
public class InvoiceLogDto
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Is it ok/a good practice to inject an `IUserService` in the profile class used to map from `Invoice` to `InvoiceLogDto` to fill the `UserName` property?

Example:

```
public class InvoiceLogMapping : Profile
{
    public InvoiceLogMapping(IUserService userService)
    {
        CreateMap<Invoice, InvoiceLogDto>()
        .ForMember(t => t.UserName, t => t.MapFrom(x => userService.GetName(x.UserId)));
    }
}
```

Comment: No, because the profile is singleton. You should inject in a cutom value resolver in this case.

Comment: @lucian You're right about that! My dependencies are scoped and profile is indeed singleton.